# What files to upload to host create-react-app website online?

Tags: reactjs, hosting, create-react-app

I am trying to upload my create-react-app site to hostgator with a custom domain. Is this as easy as just uploading all the files and folders contained in build, or there is something else I also need to upload?

Comment: Should be that easy, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Update your build folder using `yarn build` or `npm run build`. Then upload all the files of your `build` folder into the `public_html` folder and you're good to go!

If you previously deployed your website with Github pages, try to remove the "homepage" parameter as it may interfere with your path.